# Water on our planet, where did it come from?

Tags: meteorology, climate-change, oceanography

**Water on our planet, where did it come from?**

A water molecule is created when two atoms of hydrogen combine with one atom of oxygen. W

The volume of all water (on our planet) is about 332.5 million cubic miles (mi<sup>3</sup>), or 1,386 million cubic kilometers (km<sup>3</sup>). A cubic mile of water equals more than 1.1 trillion gallons. A cubic kilometer of water equals about 264 billion gallons (1 trillion liters)
https://tinyurl.com/fxa4yn69

When the water on our planet was created, how much energy was released?

**Check out “snowball earth”**
https://tinyurl.com/4ym4s3v8
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowball_Earth

Comment: Have you read, [Origin of water on Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin_of_water_on_Earth), or [How Did Water Get on Earth?](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-did-water-get-on-earth/)?

Comment: As well as [Earth's water came from space, but not in the way we thought](https://www.abc.net.au/news/science/2020-08-28/where-did-earths-water-come-from/12598198).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems likely to be AI generated... fairly non-pertinent stats (that they don't connect) and random connected link without explanation?  And just the tone doesn't sound particularly human to me?

Comment: This post contains at least two questions at once. If it were about the origins of water on Earth, it would've been a very broad question since there are multiple hypotheses. If it were about the energy released during formation of 1.4 million km³ of water that would've be an entirely different questions. The first one with a bit more focus could be on topic on this site. The other one is more of an astronomy question about origins of water in the Solar System.

Comment: On the Origins of Water in the Solar System see also https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/44951/50878